# OSM autoplot automatically alters coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap

I have noticed that the autoplot function in OpenStreetMaps seems to change the x,y axis scale in a strange way. Contrast the map produced through ggmap:

```
test1=get_map(location=c(31.00302,-4.27480,41.84012,4.291),source="osm")
ggmap(test1)
```

[image: Test1]

and the map created by OpenStreetMap's ggplot2 compatible plotting function:

```
UL=c(4.29100,31.00302)
LR=c(-4.27480,41.84012)
test2=openmap(UL,LR,type="osm")
autoplot(test2)
```

[image: Test2]

These two should be the same, but the map produced by autoplot has longitude and latitude coordinates multiplied by 100,000. How do I make it so that autoplot does not multiply everything by 100,000?

(Just renaming everything is not sufficient. I need the underlying coordinate system to reflect the numbers used above.)

Thank You.

Comment: What does `autoplot(test2, expand=F)` look like?

Comment: Do the values of test2$bbox$p1 and test2$bbox$p2 look funny as well? If so it's openmap() that's returning the funny coordinates, otherwise it is automap() that's messing with them.

Comment: `test2$bbox$p1`,`test2$bbox$p2` return `3451240.4 478119.1` and `4657620.9 -476310.7` respectively. So yes, it seems openmap() is the problem. Also, `autoplot(test2,expand=F)` plots a beige square with an x axis ticks on [903.75,904.5] and y axis on [4054430,4054431] .

Comment: I realized I can do a workaround by applying `projectMercator()` to all further interactions with the map; this lets me accommodate the weird OSM coordinates by making all coordinates weird. It is not elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to change the projection to a long/lat projection. This was accomplished by:

```
test2=openproj(test2, projection = "+proj=longlat")
```